# Multiple FXML variables to 1 controller handle

Tags: email, button, javafx, controller, fxml

How can I make a handle that applies to each of the buttons, so I don't have to make a near-identical handle for each button?

So I have a FXML file with 9 contacts, each looks like this:

```
<Button fx:id="id1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleContactEmailButtonAction" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="380.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
    <graphic>
        <VBox style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: white;">
            <children>
                <Label prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="334.0" text="Jane Doe" />
                <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="349.0" text="jdoe@britishschool.sch.ae" textAlignment="CENTER" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

And this is the controller:

```
@FXML
private Button id1; 
@FXML 
private Button id2;
@FXML 
private Button id3;
@FXML 
private Button id4;
@FXML 
private Button id5;
@FXML 
private Button id6;
@FXML 
private Button id7;
@FXML 
private Button id8;
@FXML 
private Button id9;


@FXML
protected void handleContactEmailButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    try {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        String message = "mailto:"+emailvariable+"?subject=Music%20Bookings";
        URI uri = URI.create(message);
        desktop.mail(uri);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So if button with fx:id="id1" is clicked, then email variable changes to the email in the relevant label, and all with one controller?

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Map where you can get the button from event source like:

```
@FXML
private Button id1;
@FXML
private Button id2;
@FXML
private Button id3;
@FXML
private Button id4;
@FXML
private Button id5;
@FXML
private Button id6;
@FXML
private Button id7;
@FXML
private Button id8;
@FXML
private Button id9;

private Map<Button, String> emailVariables;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
{
    emailVariables = new HashMap<Button, String>();
    emailVariables.put(id1, "id1@example.com");
    emailVariables.put(id2, "id2@example.com");
    emailVariables.put(id3, "id3@example.com");
    emailVariables.put(id4, "id4@example.com");
    emailVariables.put(id5, "id5@example.com");
    emailVariables.put(id6, "id6@example.com");
    emailVariables.put(id7, "id7@example.com");
    emailVariables.put(id8, "id8@example.com");
    emailVariables.put(id9, "i91@example.com");
}

@FXML
protected void handleContactEmailButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
{

try
{
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    String message = "mailto:" + emailvariables.get((Button) event.getSource()) + "?subject=Music%20Bookings";
    URI uri = URI.create(message);
    desktop.mail(uri);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Code is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a custom component:

```
package application;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class EmailButton extends Button {

    @FXML
    private Label nameLabel ;
    @FXML
    private Label addressLabel ;

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty emailAddress = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public EmailButton() throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("emailButton.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.load();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        nameLabel.textProperty().bind(name);
        addressLabel.textProperty().bind(emailAddress);
    }

    @FXML
    private void sendEmail() {
        try {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            String message = "mailto:"+getEmailAddress()+"?subject=Music%20Bookings";
            URI uri = URI.create(message);
            desktop.mail(uri);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty().set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty emailAddressProperty() {
        return emailAddress ;
    }

    public final String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddressProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        emailAddressProperty().set(emailAddress);
    }
}
```

and emailButton.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>


<fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" type="Button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sendEmail" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="380.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">

    <graphic>
        <VBox style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: white;">
            <children>
                <Label fx:id="nameLabel" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="334.0" />
                <Label fx:id="addressLabel" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="349.0" textAlignment="CENTER" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </graphic>
</fx:root>
```

Now in your main FXML you can just do:

```xml
<?import application.EmailButton?>

<!-- ... -->

<EmailButton name="Jane Doe" emailAddress="jdoe@britishschool.sch.ae"/>
<EmailButton name="..." emailAddress="..." />
<EmailButton name="..." emailAddress="..."/>
```

etc